# Ignore MySQL foreign key constraints in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, testing, foreign-keys

Is there a way to override mysql foreign key constraints in a php script?

I have a query passed to mysql from php, but it fails a foreign key constraint, is there any way to get around this without altering the db schema?

I'm just doing some testing, so I'll be removing the row when I'm done.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
$pdo->query('SET foreign_key_checks = 0');
//do some stuff here
$pdo->query('SET foreign_key_checks = 1');
```

Answer (score 7):

You can execute that MySQL query to disable foreign keys check:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
```

Don't forget to enable it when you're done:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

Answer (score 2):

I have something like this in my snippet collection:

```
SET @BACKUP_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS; 
SET @@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

-- Do stuff here

SET @@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@BACKUP_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET @BACKUP_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=NULL;
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. I don't remember needing double "@@" though.

Comment: It's one of the syntaxes for session variables: `SET SESSION FOO=1`, `SET @@SESSION.FOO=1` or `SET @@FOO=1`.

Answer (score 1):

Run the query: `set FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;`

```
mysql> insert into bar values(1);
ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`test`.`bar`, CONSTRAINT `bar_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`foo_id`) REFERENCES `foo` (`foo_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE)
mysql> set FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
mysql> insert into bar values(1);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: OP asked for a PHP script, not a terminal command