# how to delete result from this query?

Tags: mysql

How to delete from database result of this query?
can you guys help me please

```
SELECT v.type
FROM poll_answers
JOIN vote_types v ON poll_answers.vote_id = v.id
JOIN poll_questions q ON q.id = poll_answers.question_id
WHERE q.referendum_id =1
```

I tried to remove it id one by one but it i had problems with foreign keys so I want to remove step by step

thank you

Comment: What are you trying to delete, poll_answers, vote_types, or poll_questions.  Or are you trying to delete all of them?

Comment: @aglassman I'm trying to delete all of them where referendum_id = 1 etc in other words I want to remove all questions and answers that correspond to chosen poll

Comment: @takeit you want from delete from poll_answer, vote_type and poll_question tables a row??

Comment: @jcho360 yes, I want to remove from poll_answers, vote_types and poll_questions rows that corresponds to selected poll id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
delete poll_answerpoll_answer,v,q,
FROM poll_answers
JOIN vote_types v ON poll_answers.vote_id = v.id
JOIN poll_questions q ON q.id = poll_answers.question_id
WHERE q.referendum_id =1
```

**EDIT**

```
mysql> delete poll_answers,v,q
    -> FROM poll_answers
    -> JOIN vote_types v ON poll_answers.vote_id = v.id
    -> JOIN poll_questions q ON q.id = poll_answers.question_id
    -> WHERE q.referendum_id =1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: gives me: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM poll_answers JOIN vote_types v ON poll_answers.vote_id = v.id JOIN poll_que' at line 2` any idea why ? and I corrected `delete poll_answer` to `delete poll_answers`

Comment: @takeit that doesn't make sense, can you put part of the db in sqlfiddle?: sqlfiddle.com

Comment: this doesnt work, display some errors all the time so I put it to pastebin: http://pastebin.com/g1tbd7VA

Comment: @takeit try again I has a extra coma and I fix the 'answers'

Comment: ok it seems that query works but, still gives me error about foreign keys `#1451 - Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`db`.`poll_answers`, CONSTRAINT `poll_answers_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`question_id`) REFERENCES `poll_questions` (`id`))`

Comment: yeap, I knew it!, that's because you are deleting the PK and the FK at the same time, and for restriction you are not able to delete a FK without delete first the PK

Comment: you can try but it's 99% not recommended: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4268801/ignore-mysql-foreign-key-constraints-in-php

Comment: I executed first: `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;` then executed your code and it gave me same error, its just school project so it doesnt have to be professional, all I want is just remove those data somehowm any ideas why it doesnt work again ?

Comment: @takeit I'm sure that's because you are trying to delete a FK without delete first the PK, try adding @@, SET @@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;